# How Can I change order of figures in list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I would like to change order of special figures in list of figures, i.e.
[image: Example]

Can you help?

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
 \begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{myimage}
\caption{Three dimensions }
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{myimage}
        \caption{Four dimensions}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{myimage} 
        \caption{Two dimentions}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I use xepersian package output is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Is there any useful reason for this reordering?

Comment: The example does not compile because `myimage` is a file unavailable to us. Use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` to make the file compilable

Comment: I use xepersian package. when I use minipage environment figures order from right to left!

Comment: Your document has `Three`, `Four` and `Two` dimensions, the screen shot shows the `Four dimensions` entry twice.

Comment: It is not important

Comment: @K.Ahmadi: Well, it is important since the confusing figure order needs some conjunction with the figure caption. I understand the reading direction changes to right to left,

Comment: When I use xepersian package list of figures appears as follows:

Comment: "I would like to change the order..." Do tell us which order you wish to achieve, and do tell us why it's apparently not possible to achieve the preferred order by rearranging the way the figure environments occur.

Comment: @K.Ahmadi: I can't use the `xepersian` package since I neither understand Urdu or Farsi nor do I have the fonts installed

Comment: Since `xepersian` would appear to be essential to the work you're trying to get done, you ought to provide an example in which it occurs. Otherwise, the chances that any solution that might be offered actually works for you are slim, at best.