# How Can I change order of side by side figures?

Tags: floats

I want to place two figures like this on the page:

```
Fig2.  Fig1.
```

How do I achieve this using methods in LaTeX?
The Two figures need to have different caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
 \begin{document}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{}
        \caption{Four dimensions}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{} 
        \caption{Two dimentions}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397400/how-can-i-change-order-of-figures-in-list-of-figures

Comment: It is about list of figures. Here I want to change order of side by side figures in display.

Comment: You are missing the minimal working example, just like in the other question. Nobody will be able to guess that the question is about RTL typesetting and not just about switching numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to effect right-to-left figures, one can use a double mirror image with `\scalebox{-1}[1]`.

Note: `\centering` is overwhelmed by `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
 \begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{-1}[1]{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \scalebox{-1}[1]{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{}
        \caption{Four dimensions}
      \end{minipage}}%
      \hfill
      \scalebox{-1}[1]{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{} 
        \caption{Two dimentions}
      \end{minipage}}%
    \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I use \scalebox{-1}[1] for floatrow Packge?

Comment: Beats me.  Try it and see.  Use it \ffigbox or \fcapside.  Do not try to use it on the caption by itself.