# How Can I put two figures beside in floatrow environment?

Tags: floats, floatrow, xepersian

I have written my PhD thesis in Persian language using xepersian package. I want to put two figures beside. I use floatrow environment. In this case, figure 1 appears in left and figure 2 appears in right. How can I change this order? In other words, is there idea that figure 2 appears in left and figure 1 appears in right?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
 \ffigbox{}{\caption{A}\label{A}}
\ffigbox{}{\caption{B}\label{B}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I can use `\minipage` environment for this work(please see
[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397465/how-can-i-change-order-of-side-by-side-figures/397488?noredirect=1#comment989045_397488)).
 But in list of figures, Figure 1 appears after Figure 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it works on floatrow exactly the same as minipages.  You do, however, need some sort of figure to set the width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\scalebox{-1}[1]{\begin{floatrow}
\scalebox{-1}[1]{\ffigbox{\rule{0.4\textwidth}{.25in}}{\caption{A}\label{A}}}
\scalebox{-1}[1]{\ffigbox{\rule{0.4\textwidth}{.25in}}{\caption{B}\label{B}}}
\end{floatrow}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```